# Problems with shinyFiles::shinyDirChoose() + visNetwork... shape="icon"

Tags: r, shiny, visnetwork

I am working on a Shiny app that allows users to choose a folder with `shinyFiles::shinyDirChoose()` and then renders an interactive visualization involving the files in that folder using `visNetwork`.  All works well unless I include icons / `addFontAwesome()`, in which case `shinyDirChoose()` does not show folders and files. Is there a fix, or is this a bug? If the latter, which package, `shinyFiles` or `visNetwork`?

Here is a MWE. In this example, for the sake of simplicity, choosing the folder is not related to the visualization, but it still reproduces the error.  The example is based on `visNetwork` examples found here: https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/image_icon.html and running `shinyFiles::shinyFilesExample()`

```
library(magrittr)

server <- function(input, output) {

  volumes <- shinyFiles::getVolumes()

  shinyFiles::shinyDirChoose(input, "directory", roots=volumes)

  output$directorypath <- shiny::renderPrint({shinyFiles::parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)})

  output$network <- visNetwork::renderVisNetwork({

    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:5, group = c(rep("A", 2), rep("B", 3)))
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,5,3,3), to = c(1,2,4,2))

    visNetwork::visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% 

      visNetwork::visGroups(groupname = "A", shape = "icon", 
                icon = list(code = "f0e3", color = "darkblue")) %>% 

       visNetwork::visGroups(groupname = "B", shape = "icon",
                 icon = list(code = "f000", color = "red")) %>% 

       visNetwork::addFontAwesome()

  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  shinyFiles::shinyDirButton("directory", "Folder select", "Please select a folder"),

  shiny::verbatimTextOutput("directorypath"), 

  visNetwork::visNetworkOutput("network")
)

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If the icon pieces are removed, that is, the `visGroups` lines are changed to:

```
  visNetwork::visGroups(groupname = "A", color = "darkblue") %>% 

  visNetwork::visGroups(groupname = "B", color = "red")
```

it works fine. (The `visNetwork::addFontAwesome()` line is not the problem.)

I'm baffled.